# Responding HTML and JSON from php at the same time

Tags: php, html, json, optimization

Imagine a page on a website, this page has many elements printed in html directly from server backend and others being printed throught JS with data based on JSON. With the first load of the page it comes all the HTML layout and his elements printed by php in the response in the same request some JSON is printed in the  section in order to being parsed by a JS funcions and templates..After that that JSON can be updated over another request to a JSON rest api

Is a good practice to do that?? The main reason to do that is to avoid make two request in the first page load... Imagine $data_array is a enormous data object

```
echo $entire_page_html;    
echo '<script>'.'var data_source = '.json_enconde($data_array);.'</script>';
```

Thanks in advide!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that.

Although currently your code is invalid, from a PHP *and* JavaScript perspective:

- `json_encode()` has only 1 `n`.
- Don't add a semi-colon mid concatenation
- You are echoing a JSON string, which'll be something like `{"a":"b"}`. This won't have quotes around it, which will produce a JavaScript error.

```
echo $entire_page_html;    
echo "<script> var data_source = '" . json_encode($data_array) . "'</script>";
// Quotes have been added ---Here^------------------------and-Here^
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the typos in the code... I was wonrriying about the ugly that the page loogs when looking the code. Before acepting your answer I'll wait for the opinion of someone else

Comment: @JavierdelSaz By all means.